# How to create product attribute and assign it to specific attribute set and attribute set group? Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, eav-attributes

I have an attribute set with name `Gold` and attribute set group with name `Ring`, i want to add a boolean product attribute with name `biodynamic` like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;


class AddBiodynamicProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'biodynamic',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Biodynamic',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'backend' => '',
                'sort_order' => '9996',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'default' => null,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple',
                'attribute_set' => 'Gold',
                'group' => 'Ring',
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'option' => array('values' => array(""))
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'biodynamic');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

but the above code will not put the product attribute to the `Gold` attribute set

Comment: your attribute is added to database ? can you see attribute in admin ?

Comment: @Pawan yes i can see it

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: could you please update full file code in question ?

Comment: @Pawan i just updated my full code

Comment: did you tried my code ? just add my code before `$this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();`. I just checked and it is working fine!

Comment: any luck ? attribute added in attribute set or have any issue ?

Comment: its added to the default group, not the one i wanted @Pawan

Comment: did you change "Default" to  "Gold" and "General" to "Ring" from code ? i used `Default` in my example and you need to change attribute set and group name!

Comment: @jojo have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute to attribute set by method `addAttributeToGroup` :

```
$attributeId = $eavSetup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'biodynamic'); // get attribute ID

$eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', 'Default', 'General', $attributeId,null);

where:

catalog_product = entity type id
Default = Attribute set
General = group name
```

As you already run install script, you need to upgrade version of module and need to upgrade setup to run install schema

Hope above will help!